# How can I save Firefox bookmarks to a file the same way it is shown in the browser?

Tags: firefox, browser, database, bookmarks

I have a massive amount of bookmarks in my browser (Firefox) and I want to store a list of bookmarks stored in each folder in my external drive. How can I save them in a similar way as they are displayed in Firefox bookmarks?
I do not want to copy/paste their links in a text file since I also want to store the title of the website and there creation date.
As there are folders involved and I do not want to export all the bookmarks, I can not use export function of Firefox.

Comment: “export” is the obvious answer to your question.  Please explain more clearly why you “can not” use the export function. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this addon to export partly  your bookmarks https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/free-export-bookmarks  (but its not cover case - of showing bookmark data creation)

(Also, you can sort bookmarks by date via this addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sort-bookmarks-by-date before you try to export them by first addon. And may be this flow cover your request)